# Unable to deploy an application on Heroku due to some port problems

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I've been trying to deploy a repository https://github.com/evelynhathaway/triton-poll to heroku, but since I am fairly new to NodeJs, I am unable to detect the problem. But I guess it's due to the port because heroku doesn't use static ports.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Is there any error message? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Shows H10 on heroku

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the fork and you did a couple of mistakes. I don't have the time to fix, test and get it to run but I can show you how I solved it before.

All the relevant code changes can be found in this commit (different project):
https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/commit/63730fd7f44d2716a31fcae55990d83c84d5ffea

1. The project is divided into a client and server part.
   You can see here, https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/blob/63730fd7f44d2716a31fcae55990d83c84d5ffea/script/websock.js#L16, how I combined server and client into one. This only works because the static client files are served via `http/https` and the server uses websocket, no http `ws/wss`
2. When you publish a server on Heroku you need to bind to their dynamic port. However when you want to access the web server you do **not** specify a port. The hostname is automatically translated into an ip-address + port combo. I did this here: https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/blob/63730fd7f44d2716a31fcae55990d83c84d5ffea/web/main.js#L44 When deployed on Heroku the `socketURL` does not contain a port number.
3. Finally you bind to the server. I did it here https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/blob/63730fd7f44d2716a31fcae55990d83c84d5ffea/script/websock.js#L55 and here https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/blob/63730fd7f44d2716a31fcae55990d83c84d5ffea/socket-config.js#L30

You also have to make sure that your clients files are built properly and served.